# c# object initialization - possible to reference properties by non-literal name?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Trying to write a data-driven data mapping utility. But I need to be able to initialize objects (rows in a list) referencing the property (column) names as variables.

So for example instead of this:

```
var p = new person {name = "Joe", age = 10}
```

can I do something like...

```
string prop1 = "name", prop2 = "age";
var p = new person {[prop1] = "Joe", [prop2] = 10}
```

...or, could we treat the properties as an ordered collection somehow, like

```
var p = new person {prop[1] = "Joe", prop[2] = 10}
```

...or implicitly order them by simply dropping the property names, assuming the properties would be implied...

```
var p = new person {"Joe", 10}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at reflection? Object initializers are just syntactic sugar for setters anyway. They don't affect how you work with an object at all

Comment: Maybe a dictionary of `string` and `object` would be a better idea for a source?

Comment: @KarlRKaiser what are you really trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Obviously, you want some way to set properties dynamically, but why? Wouldn't that be solved eg with AutoMapper or a similar tool?

Comment: ...Whatever it takes - I simply cannot use the literal property names, but I have to map string values into the properties somehow, and I don't mind writing an iterating method, or whatever, to do it.

Comment: ...I'm trying to do what I have done for decades - to abstract data mapping because maintaining the mappings in a table form is easier then in code. In an environment like FoxPro one can "macro" anything, which provides the flexibility to do this sort of thing at will, but I'm stuck with typing rules in c#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `person.GetType().GetProperty(prop1).SetValue(person,"Joe");` Of course you need to add nullchecking on the `GetProperty`.

Comment: In other words, use Reflection.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I'm looking for.

Might as well ask: is there a way to *also* reference the object as a dynamic name, so that the whole assignment expression would not have a literal object or property name.

Comment: You can use `Type.GetType("your.full.namespace.class")`

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot do that. The only thing you can do to achieve this is use reflection to set properties:

```
var p = new person();
var nameProp = typeof(person).GetProperty('name');
nameProp.SetValue(p, "Joe");
```

to have implicit order of properties you can declare constructor:

```
class person
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    //...
    person(string name, int age){
       this.name = name; 
       //...
    }
```

and call

```
new person("Joe",44);
```

Comment: ...so **typeof(person).GetProperty('name')** is effectively a reference to the property itself, which can be used to assign a value? It looks like that would work.

Comment: Kind of; Its an object that allows access to all metadata regarding property and allows setting its value. Yet I would advise against heavy use of reflection in any project. You should read more about it before you start using it.

Comment: If I can set the value of a property by referencing it through metadata or as an evaluated property/datum, and not its literal name, I'll be fine. I don't know if I'd call the use "heavy" but data mapping has always worked best for me through a data-driven rule-based system because of the flexibility it offers in customizing or changing the mapping rules without also requiring recompilation and deployment of code.

Then if that works I'll come back and ask how to reference OBJECTS as metadata ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be using reflection:

```
var person = new Person();
person.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(person, "Joe");
```